# Implementing discrete and continuous Hilbert transforms

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, signal-processing, integral-transforms

What is an efficient and accurate *Mathematica* implementation of the [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform), for both continuous and especially discretely sampled functions?

This transform relates phase and amplitude in [minimum phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_phase) systems.

Answer (score 29):

Here's a direct implementation of the formula

$$\mathcal H(u)(t) = \frac1{\pi} -\hspace{-1.1em}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u(\tau)}{t-\tau}\, \mathrm d\tau$$

```
hilbertTransform[f_, u_, t_] :=
       FullSimplify[Convolve[f, 1/u, u, t, PrincipalValue -> True]/π]
```

Try it out:

```
hilbertTransform[#, v, w] & /@ {Sin[v], Cos[v], 1/(1 + v^2), Sinc[v], DiracDelta[v]}
   {-Cos[w], Sin[w], w/(1 + w^2), (1 - Cos[w])/w, 1/(π w)}
```

---

For the discrete Hilbert transform, here is a *Mathematica* routine:

```
hilbert[data_?VectorQ] := Module[{fopts = FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, e, n},
   e = Boole[EvenQ[n = Length[data]]]; 
   Im[InverseFourier[Fourier[data, fopts] * 
                     PadRight[ArrayPad[ConstantArray[2, Quotient[n, 2] - e], {1, e}, 1], n],
                     fopts]]] /; And @@ Thread[Im[data] == 0]
```

(making everything completely analogous to `FourierTransform[]` and `Fourier[]`). The algorithm is based on the routine in [Marple's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ACSSC.1997.679118), and is essentially the same algorithm used by the function `hilbert()` in MATLAB's Signal Processing Toolbox.

Examples:

```
hilbert[{1, -2, 1}]
   {1.73205, 0., -1.73205}

hilbert[{1, -2, 1, 2}]
   {2., 0., -2., 0.}
```

Comment: @ J.M.is away when I try your `hilbertTransform` with the first 3 tests, all give me the right answers as yours, but for the last one, `hilbertTransform[DiracDelta[v], v, w]` gives `Convolve[DiracDelta[v], 1/v, v, w, PrincipalValue -> True]/\[Pi]`, which is unevaluated and different your output. How to fix it? I am based on v11.3.0.0 and win7. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it seems the behavior of `Convolve[]` has changed in succeeding versions. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @J.M.isinlimbo how to apply the discrete `hilbert` function on an `InterpolatingFunction`, can you help with [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214671/plot-a-nested-integration-of-an-interporatingfunction-correctly)?

Answer (score 28):

You can realize a discrete Hilbert transform by convolving your discrete signal with a Hilbert kernel. The convolution is implemented with least effort in the frequency domain, where the spectrum of the Hilbert kernel is $$\sigma_H(\omega)=-i\cdot\mathrm{sgn}(\omega)$$ where $\omega$ is the angular frequency.

**Continuous case**

We define a function to perform the convolution in the frequency domain for us

```
HilbertTransform[f_,u_,t_] := Module[{fp = FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, x},
    InverseFourierTransform[
      -I (2 HeavisideTheta[x] - 1) FourierTransform[f, u, x, fp],
      x, t, fp
    ]
]
```

by exploiting the [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) and getting the result back to our domain of interest via an inverse Fourier transform. In this case the `HeavisideTheta` function turns out to be better suited for modeling $\mathrm{sgn}(\omega)$ than the more intuitive `Sign` function, which can give wrong results in extreme cases like `DiracDelta`.

Some results for the test cases from J.M.'s answer:

```
In[1] := HilbertTransform[#, v, w] & /@
             {Sin[v], Cos[v], 1/(1 + v^2), Sinc[v], DiracDelta[v]}
Out[1] = {-Cos[w], Sin[w], w/(w^2+1), 1/w-Cos[w]/w, 1/(π w)}
```

**Discrete case**

In the discrete case we prepare the phase shifts for the occurring frequencies for a given data size `n`

```
HilbertSpectrum[0] := {};
HilbertSpectrum[n_Integer?Positive] := With[{nhalf = Quotient[n - 1, 2]},
  Join[{0}, ConstantArray[-I, nhalf], If[EvenQ[n], {0}, {}]
          , ConstantArray[ I, nhalf]
  ]
];
```

which we can then use in

```
Hilbert[data_?VectorQ, padding_Integer?NonNegative] := Module[
  {fp = FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, n = Length[data], m, paddeddata},
  m = n + padding;
  paddeddata = PadRight[data, m];
  Re @ InverseFourier[ HilbertSpectrum[m] Fourier[paddeddata, fp], fp][[;;n]]
]
```

which, like its continuous counterpart, performs the convolution in frequency space. To reduce artifacts due to circular convolution in case of nonperiodic signals we can choose to pad the `data` with zeros before convolution and cut to its original length after the transform. If we apply it to a simple sine wave

```
With[{n = 128}, sinedata = N@Table[Sin[2 π 3 k/n], {k, n}];]
     ListLinePlot[{sinedata, Hilbert[sinedata, 0]}]
```

this results in a good approximation of an inverted cosine:

[image: Hilbert transform of a sine wave]

But we can also try the transform on more interesting waveforms, for example a sine with continuously changing frequency

```
With[{n = 128}, sinedata = N@Table[Sin[2 π k/15 k/n], {k, n}];]
     ListLinePlot[{sinedata, Hilbert[sinedata, 256]}]
```

[image: Hilbert transform of sine wave with increasing frequency]

or a transition between different waveforms

```
With[{n = 128},
  data = N@Join[
    Table[TriangleWave[3 k/n], {k, n}], 
    Table[SquareWave[3 k/n], {k, n}]
  ];
]
ListLinePlot[{data, Hilbert[data, 256]}]
```

[image: Hilbert transform of a triangle wave followed by a square wave]

Comment: Your implementation of the positive integer case of `HilbertSpectrum[]` can be compacted a bit: `HilbertSpectrum[n_Integer?Positive] := PadRight[ArrayPad[ConstantArray[-I, Quotient[n - 1, 2]], {1, Boole[EvenQ[n]]}], n, I]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I like the use of `ArrayPad` with `Boole` and I haven't thought of using the more canonical `Quotient`. I'll adapt the use of `Quotient`. I think I'll still mainly stick with my current version because it's faster and I think it's a bit easier to see what the code is doing.

Comment: Recently I've been trying to modify Hilbert[data_?VectorQ, padding_Integer?NonNegative] function to work with 2D data. While it's clear how to apply Fourier to matrices I'm lost with HilbertSpectrum. How does it look like for 2D data? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

For continuous signal, I think is easy, took this in a course. For discrete, hard for me, we did not study it at school (yet).

But if the signal is  continuous, this gives the Hilbert transform of the signal:

```
f[t_] := Sin[t];
g = FourierTransform[f[t], t, omega];
InverseFourierTransform[I* Sign[omega]*g, omega, t]
```

==>

```
-Cos[t]
```

P.S. I just saw a reference for the original paper for the implementation of discrete Hilbert transform. ([link reference](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/PROC.1970.7696)) by Kak, 1970.

**note(1)**

Just did a search on the net, and found what seems like a good reference with lots of Mathematica code for Hilbert transform, and a code for the discrete one. Reference is *Handbook of geophysical exploration, volume 1 by Klaus Helbig and Sven Treitel*. And [on page 162](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOF4y.png), they give the implementation:

```
hilbert[RealTrace_] := (lh = Length[RealTrace];
   If[OddQ[lh], lh2 = Ceiling[lh/2], lh2 = lh/2];
   fd = Fourier[RealTrace, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
   Do[fd[[i]] = fd[[i]]*E^(+I*Pi/2), {i, lh2 + 1, lh}];
   Do[fd[[i]] = fd[[i]]*E^(-I*Pi/2), {i, 1, lh2}];
   QuadratureTrace = 
    Re[Chop[InverseFourier[fd, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]];);
```

Here is a link to the on-line version I saw the above ([link here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53512135/46/Hilbert-Transforms)) if you like to read more about it.

**note(2)**

I wrote the function from the book above to make it easy for others to use, here it is below, and put a quick Manipulate around it, used the triangle and square functions shown in the other answer here to make it to compare.

[image: Manipulate object for Hilbert transform]

```
Manipulate[Module[{data1, data2, k, opts},
  opts = {
    ImageSize -> {300}, ImagePadding -> 20, AxesLabel -> {"n", "ht(n)"}, 
    PlotLabel -> Text@Row[{Style["data", Blue], Spacer[10], 
    Style["Hilbert", Red]}], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Tiny}, Joined -> True
  };
  data1 = N@Table[TriangleWave[3 k/n], {k, n}];
  data2 = N@Table[SquareWave[3 k/n], {k, n}];

  Grid[{
    {ListPlot[{data1, hilbert[data1]}, opts]},
    {ListPlot[{data2, hilbert[data2]}, opts]}
    }, Frame -> All]
  ],    
 {{n, 32, "number of points"}, 32, 256, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 Initialization :>
  (       
   (*function below is from Handbook of geophysical exploration,       
     volume 1 by Klaus Helbig and Sven Treitel, page 162*)

   hilbert[RealTrace_] := Module[{lh, fd, lh2, i},
     lh = Length[RealTrace];
     If[OddQ[lh], lh2 = Ceiling[lh/2], lh2 = lh/2];
     fd = Fourier[RealTrace, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
     Do[fd[[i]] = fd[[i]]*E^(I*Pi/2), {i, lh2 + 1, lh}];
     Do[fd[[i]] = fd[[i]]*E^(-I*Pi/2), {i, 1, lh2}];
     QuadratureTrace = 
      Re[Chop[InverseFourier[fd, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]]
     ]
   )
 ]
```

Comment: A little improvement: `hilbert[RealTrace_] := Block[{fd, i}, fd = I Fourier[RealTrace, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]; Do[fd[[i]] *= -1, {i, Ceiling[Length[RealTrace]/2]}]; Re[InverseFourier[fd, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]]`

Comment: @Nasser Given the property of Hilbert transform: $\mathcal{F}[\mathcal{H}[f]](\omega)=-i sign(\omega)\mathcal{F}[f](\omega)$. So we can take inverse Fourier on both sides to get the Hilbert transformation. But why there is not minus sign before `I` in `InverseFourierTransform[I* Sign[omega]*g, omega, t]`? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Nasser I checked this and tried it and the command f[t_] := Sin[t];
g = FourierTransform[f[t], t, omega];
InverseFourierTransform[I* Sign[omega]*g, omega, t]
 is exactly the same as FourierTransform[f[t], t, omega]. There is no difference between them. How can Hilbert transform be the same as Fourier transform?

Comment: @Vangsnes  Could you show screen shot? in V 13.2 `FourierTransform[f[t], t, omega]` is not the same as `InverseFourierTransform[I*Sign[omega]*g, omega, t]` ? Or may be I did not understand you. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzD28.png)

Comment: @Nasser I paste  function here

     points = {{-5, 0}, {-4.8, 3}, {-4.5, 1}, {-4.2, 1}, {-4, 3.5}, {-3.8, 
    0}, {-3.5, 6}, {-3.1, 0}, {-3, -5.5}, {-2.8, 0}, {-2.5, 6}, {-2.1,
     0}, {-1.8, -2.5}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1.2, 5}, {-0.8, 
    0}, {-0.5, -8}, {-0.2, 0}, {0, 18}, {1/2, 0}, {2/3, -8}, {1, 
    0}, {4/3, 4}, {3/2, 0}, {1.6, -4}, {2, 3}, {2.5, -3}, {3, 
    3}, {3.2, -2}, {3.5, 2}, {3.8, -4}, {4.2, 0}, {4.5, 
    6}, {4.8, -5}, {5, 0.1}};
f[t_] := Piecewise[
  Table[{points[[i, 2]], points[[i, 1]] > t}, {i, Length[points]}], 0]

Comment: When I tried your transforms I got the same plot! This is why I dont understand how they are different

Comment: @Nasser I found the reason of the problem: 

f[t_] := Sin[t];
g = FourierTransform[f[t], t, omega];
InverseFourierTransform[I* Sign[omega]*g, omega, t]


should rather be:

f[t_] := Sin[t];
g = FourierTransform[f[t], t, omega];
h=InverseFourierTransform[I* Sign[omega]*g, omega, t]

Where h is the Hilbert transform . Thanks for your work, it is as always, excellent!

Comment: @Vangsnes Yes that is correct, `InverseFourierTransform[I* Sign[omega]*g, omega, t]` is the Hilbert transform. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Nasser. Great work!!

Answer (score 2):

All the functions presented here make use of Fourier transforms to calculate the discrete Hilbert transform in frequency space. One can of course also compute the Hilbert transform directly in position space:

```
HilbertDirect = Compile[{{data, _Real, 1}},
   Table[
         2/\[Pi] 
         Sum[ 
              data[[i]]/(j - i)
         , {i, 1 + Mod[j, 2],Length[data] - Mod[j, 2], 2}]
   , {j, 1, Length[data]}]
]
```

Or, with slightly improved sensitivity for higher frequency components:

```
HilbertDirect2 = Compile[{{data, _Real, 1},{nn, _Integer}},
   Table[
        2/nn 
        Sum[
            data[[i]] Cot[((j - i) \[Pi])/nn]
        , {i,1 + Mod[j, 2], Length[data] - Mod[j, 2], 2}]
   , {j, 1, Length[data]}]
]
```

(where one should set `nn>=Length[data]`).

In most cases, this is of course slower than the Fourier transform approach, since the above scales directly with `Length[data]`. However, the quality of this finite impulse response Hilbert transform seems pretty good. Especially the edge effects for non-periodic cases are better than low padding frequency space results.