# Convolution integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convolution

I want to calculate the following integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d \omega f(\omega) g(\omega'\pm\omega)$$

where $f$ has the form
$$f(\omega)=\frac{a}{\omega- \omega_0\pm i \eta}$$ and $g$ has a similar expression. $\eta$ is a infinitesimal positive number.

What is the best way of evaluating (in a symbolic way) the convolution integral?

I tried the following command but it does not work

```
Integrate[
    1/(ω - 3 - I η) 1/(ω' - ω - 6.3 + I η),
    {ω, -Infinity, Infinity}
]
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `Integrate`?

Comment: Integrate does not work

Comment: Please share the code for what you have tried. Users here don't want to spend time converting the expressions into Mathematica code and it helps to know what has already been tried.

Comment: The following command Integrate[
 1/(\[Omega] - 3 - I *\[Eta])/(\[Omega]1 - \[Omega] - 63/10 + 
    I*\[Eta] ), {\[Omega], -Infinity, Infinity}] outputs ConditionalExpression[0, 
 Re[\[Eta]] > 0 && Im[\[Omega]1] + Re[\[Eta]] > 0]. I have no time to investigate why.

Comment: Imaginary part is just $\mp \pi a g(\omega\pm\omega_0)$. A standard way to compute the real part is via the Hilbert transform. See here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/341/implementing-discrete-and-continuous-hilbert-transforms

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that *Mathematica* has a specific use for the `'` character (namely `Derivative`).  Changing `ω'` to `ωp` gives

```
Integrate[1/(ω - 3 - I η) 1/(ωp - ω - 6.3 + I η), {ω, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[0. + 0. I, Im[(0. + 1. I) η + 1. ωp] > 0 && Re[η] > 0]

Or you can use the built in function [`Convolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Convolve.html) as

```
Convolve[1/(ω - 3 - I η), 1/(ω - 6.3 + I η), ω, ωp]
```

> 0.

And if I've generalized correctly with

```
f[ω_] := a/(ω - ω0 - I η)
g[ω_] := a/(ω - ω1 + I η)
```

then

```
Convolve[f[ω], g[ω], ω, ωp]
% /. {a -> 1, ω0 -> 3, ω1 -> 6.3}
```

> a^2 Convolve[1/(-I η + ω - ω0), 1/(I η + ω - ω1), ω, ωp]
>
> 0.

Which is not very satisfying because we still have an unevaluated `Convolve`.  But if we allow for conditions

```
Convolve[f[ω], g[ω], ω, ωp, GenerateConditions -> True]
% /. {a -> 1, ω0 -> 3, ω1 -> 6.3}
```

> ConditionalExpression[0, Im[ω0] + Re[η] > 0 && Im[ω1] < Re[η]]
>
> ConditionalExpression[0, Re[η] > 0]

we get something that agrees with the above, and is a little more satisfying (at least to me).