# Plot nested integration of an InterpolatingFunction efficiently

Tags: plotting, functions, numerical-integration

Suppose we have an `InterpolatingFunction` from `NDSolve`

```
L = 5;

sol = First@NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], u[x, 0] == 0, 
      u[-5, t] == Sin[t], u[5, t] == 0}, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Defining the functions:

```
int1st[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[D[Evaluate[u[s, t] /. sol], s]*Cot[(π (x - s))/(2*L)], {s, -L, x, L}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"];

intNest[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[D[Evaluate[u[xp, t] /. sol], xp]*int1st[xp, t]*Cot[(π (x - xp))/(2*L)], {xp, -L, x, L}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"];
```

which are, respectively, similar to the [circular Hilbert transform of a periodic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) and its nest (please see the section 'Hilbert transform on the circle' on that webpage). Note in `intNest`, `int1st` is called with `xp` as its argument, which acts as the variable of integration of `intNest`.

For example, plotting `int1st` at `tn=5;` I obtain the curve within 25s.

```
tn=5;
Plot[int1st[x,tn], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, All}, ImageSize -> 400, PlotPoints -> 60, AspectRatio -> 0.5, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
```

[image]

My problem is on `intNest`: when plotting it, there is no warning but my computer runs for hours without output. **Is my definition of the `intNest` correct. If correct, how to make it more efficient?**

```
Plot[intNest[x, tn], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, All}, ImageSize -> 400, PlotPoints -> 60, AspectRatio -> 0.5, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320330/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed), I modified the function definitions:

```
ClearAll[int1st, intNest];

Block[{x, t}, int1st[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] = NIntegrate[D[u[s, t] /. sol, s]*Cot[(π (x - s))/(2*L)], {s, -L, x, L}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]];

Block[{x, t}, intNest[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] = NIntegrate[D[u[xp, t] /. sol, xp]*int1st[xp, t]*Cot[(π (x - xp))/(2*L)], {xp, -L, x, L}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]];
```

**Findings: `int1st` can be plotted well in about 20s (same result as above), but it is still very slow to plot `intNest`.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: Used the built-in `"InterpolationPointSubdivision"` method.

Update 2: Memoization helps because the subdivision is at the same points (given by `xcoords` in the code below) every time.  So in `intNest2[]`, the call `int1st2[xp, t]` will initially be made at the same `xp` for each subinterval, unless the subinterval contains the singular point `x`.  I say, "initially," because the recursive subdivision of each subinterval in the `intNest2[]` call may be different depending on the value of `x` and its effect on the complete integrand.

Some explanation in the comments.  If I have more time, I might be able to add more:

```
L = 5;

(* OP's *)
ClearAll[int1st, intNest];
int1st[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Derivative[1, 0][u /. sol][s, t]*
    Cot[(π (x - s))/(2*L)], {s, -L, x, L}, 
   Method -> "PrincipalValue"];

intNest[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   D[Evaluate[u[xp, t] /. sol], xp]*int1st[xp, t]*
    Cot[(π (x - xp))/(2*L)], {xp, -L, x, L}, 
   Method -> "PrincipalValue"];

(* with singularity removed from NIntegrate and 
 * manual interpolating nodes subdivision *)
ClearAll[int1st2, intNest2];

(* interpolating nodes *)
{xcoords, tcoords} = u["Coordinates"] /. sol;

mem : int1st2[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] :=
  mem = Block[{s}, (* memoization seems to help with Plot[] *)
    With[{
      du = Derivative[1, 0][u /. sol],
      dux = Derivative[1, 0][u /. sol][x, t]},
     NIntegrate[
       Piecewise[{{du[s, t]*Cot[(π (x - s))/(2*L)] - 
           dux (2*L)/(π (x - s)), x != s}}], (* subtract singular part *)
       {s, -L, x, L},
       Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", (* divide interval at nodes *)
         "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0},
       PrecisionGoal -> 4 (* PDE solution is low-precision *)
       ] + dux ( (2*L) Log[(L + x)/(L - x)])/π (* add PV integral of singular part *)
     ]];

intNest2[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{xp}, 
   With[{
     du = Derivative[1, 0][u /. sol], 
     dux = Derivative[1, 0][u /. sol][x, t]*int1st2[x, t]}, 
    NIntegrate[
      Piecewise[{{du[xp, t]*int1st2[xp, t]*
           Cot[(π (x - xp))/(2*L)] - dux (2*L)/(π (x - xp)), 
         x != xp}}], {xp, -L, x, L}, 
      Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
        "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, PrecisionGoal -> 4] + 
     dux*((2*L) Log[(L + x)/(L - x)])/π]];
```

Single-call timings:

```
int1st2[4, 5] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming
int1st[4, 5] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.017778, -1.6291}
  {0.056669, -1.6291}
*)

intNest2[4, 5] // AbsoluteTiming
intNest[4, 5] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {5.96797, 1.78776}
  {52.9943, 1.78775}
*)
Plot[int1st2[x, 5], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, All}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, PlotPoints -> 60, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

There are 441 points here, so multiply by the single call timings to get an estimate of the time to plot:

```
Cases[%, Line[p_] :> Length@p, Infinity]
(*  {441}  *)
```

The nested integral is still going to be slow.  You can use options like `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` to reduce the number of points plotted (that is, reduce the number of function calls).

Comment: Nice!  Could you memoize `int1st2` to take advantage of the recycled points?

Comment: @ChrisK Memoization doesn't help with `intNest[4, 5]`. Rather doubt it would help with `Plot`, either. There aren't many integration rules that recycle points. But if the same call to `intNest` needs to be done multiple times, then obviously memoization would speed things up here.

Comment: I should have used “InterpolationPointsSubdicision”. Will update when I can log into the site (tomorrow).  The rest doesn’t matter that much. Some of it is typos. (As I implied, I didn’t have much time. )

Comment: @MichaelE2 I haven't looking into why, but memoizing with `int1st2[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := int1st2[x, t] =` allows `Plot[intNest2[x, 5], ..., PlotPoints -> 5]` to run in four minutes, whereas without memoizing it doesn't complete in at least fifteen minutes.

Comment: @Chris K, did you mean `f[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := f[x, t] =... ` can **memorize** all the data of `f[x,t]` even though it is a function of `x` and `t`?

Comment: @jsxs Whenever `f[x, t]` is called for a particular `x` and `t`, the value is stored for future use, called memoization (yeah, weird name).  See [my most popular question ever](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean) for more info.

Comment: @ChrisK OK, I guess I did something wrong in testing. Even the single calls are faster this morning.

Comment: @ChrisK I think I understand why memoization helps, and why it doesn't help much on the initial call to `intNest2[]`.  The key is explained in "Update 2."

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah that's what I suspected.  Thanks for the update!

Comment: @MichaelE2 when I try the update code to plot `intNest2`, I got the warnings:>> Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Total[...] and obtained an empty plot.

Comment: @jsxs I get no such error, but the `Total[]` was an unnecessary relic, so I removed it.  Perhaps you have a latent definition, which is a common reason one user gets an error and another does not. Restarting the kernel usually fixes such a problem. I doubt it's a version issue, but I'm using 12.0.0.

Comment: @MichaelE2, now it works. Thanks. Now I understand `+dux ((2*L) Log[(L + x)/(L - x)])/\[Pi]` adds the PV integral of the subtracted part. Just one last question: could u explain why, e.g. by `-dux (2*L)/(\[Pi] (x - s))` we subtract the singularity?

Comment: @jsxs The function $f(t)\cot at$ has a Laurent series expansion ${f(0) \over a t} + {f'(0)\over a}+\cdots$, so $-{f(0)\over at} + f(t) \cot at$ has no singularity at $t=0$.  So $f$ corresponds to `du`, $f(0)$ to `dux`, $a$ to `-2 Pi/L`, and $t$ to `s - x` (`s` is the independent variable). I guess the `Piecewise` function should have `{f'(0)\over a}` as the default instead of zero. It's just a single point, but in a discrete algorithm, it might be an unlikely bug waiting to happen; with `s == x` (that is, $t=0$) specified as a singularity, it should be ok, though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you. but the add PV integral of singular part seems to be wrong. $\int_{-L}^L f(0)/(at)ds=(-2L/\pi)f(0) \int_{-L}^L d(x-s)/(x-s)=f(0)(2L/\pi) \ln[(x+L)/(x-L)]$ instead of $f(0)(2L/\pi) \ln[(L + x)/(L - x)]$. Please modifiy when you confirm and have time.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The the interpolating nodes, obtained with `{xcoords, tcoords} = u["Coordinates"] /. sol;`, are not used in the subsequent computation. What is it use?