# Issue with Inverse Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm having some trouble performing an inverse Fourier transform, essentially I have a function which I can Fourier transform with seemingly no issue, but I can't inverse Fourier transform the result. My overall objective is to perform a Hilbert transform.

I have a function, found by solving a differential equation:

```
Xsol[t_] = 
DSolveValue[
            {
              X''[t] + \[Gamma] X'[t] + \[Omega]0^2 X[t] == F/m Cos[\[Omega]0 t], 
              X[0] == A0 Sin[\[Phi]0] && X'[0] == \[Omega]0 A0 Cos[\[Phi]0]
            },  X[t], t
           ] // Simplify
```

which seems to be well-behaved. I then attempt to find the Hilbert Transform of `Xsol[t]`, I found several implementations from this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/341/implementing-discrete-and-continuous-hilbert-transforms):

```
HilbertTransformMethod1[f_] := InverseFourierTransform[I * Sign[\[Omega]] * FourierTransform[f, t, \[Omega]], \[Omega], t] 
HilbertTransformMethod2[f_] := InverseFourierTransform[-I * (2 * HeavisideTheta[\[Omega]] - 1) * FourierTransform[f, t, \[Omega]], \[Omega], t]
HilbertTransformMethod3[f_] := 1/Pi * Convolve[f, 1/\[Omega], \[Omega], t, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

The third method seems to be obsolete (based on information in the [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/341/implementing-discrete-and-continuous-hilbert-transforms#comment524190_348)) due to changes in the way `Convolve[...]` behaves. The Inverse Fourier transform seems to be where the problem lies, as

```
InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[Xsol[t], t, \[Omega]], \[Omega], t]
```

returns unevaluated, which seems strange as `FourierTransform[Xsol[t], t, \[Omega]]` works with no problem.

I've tried different approaches to get the inverse Fourier transform bit working such as using `Assuming[]` to make sure that all the variables are real and $>0$, using `Integrate[]` to "directly" inverse Fourier transform, and I have also use `FourierTransform[]` but with redefined `FourierParameters` (on the off chance that `FourierTransform` and `InverseFourierTransform` behave differently)

Comment: Use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` for `Xsol` so that the differential equation is solved once and simplify the results.
`Xsol[t_] = DSolveValue[{X''[t] + ω0^2 X[t] == F/m Cos[ω0 t], X[0] == A0 Sin[φ0] && X'[0] == A0 ω0 Cos[φ0]}, X[t], t] // Simplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon My mistake, I have ommitted a term from my ODE. Let me correct the question.

Comment: I have corrected the question and the code to solve the differential equation, for some reason I didn't type my damping term...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

HilbertTransformMethod1[f_] := 
 InverseFourierTransform[
  I*Sign[ω]*FourierTransform[f, t, ω], ω, t]

HilbertTransformMethod2[f_] := 
 InverseFourierTransform[-I*(2*HeavisideTheta[ω] - 1)*
   FourierTransform[f, t, ω], ω, t]
```

Put assumptions into [`$Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) so that they are available to any function that takes the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)

```
$Assumptions = Thread[{A0, F, m, γ, ϕ0, ω0} > 0];
```

Your function simplifies further with [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html); however, it works with either.

```
Xsol[t_] = 
 DSolveValue[{X''[t] + γ X'[t] + ω0^2 X[t] == 
     F/m Cos[ω0 t], X[0] == A0 Sin[ϕ0], 
    X'[0] == ω0 A0 Cos[ϕ0]}, X[t], t] // FullSimplify

(* (F Sin[t ω0])/(m γ ω0) + 
 E^(-((t γ)/
   2)) (A0 Cosh[
      1/2 t Sqrt[γ^2 - 4 ω0^2]] Sin[ϕ0] + ((-2 F + 
       A0 m γ (2 ω0 Cos[ϕ0] + γ Sin[ϕ0])) Sinh[
      1/2 t Sqrt[γ^2 - 4 ω0^2]])/(
    m γ Sqrt[γ^2 - 4 ω0^2])) *)
```

The transform of a sum is the sum of the transforms. For complicated expressions, [`Expand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expand.html) the expression to operate on the simpler individual components.

```
HilbertTransformMethod1 /@ Expand[Xsol[t]]

(* -((E^(-I t ω0) (1 + E^(2 I t ω0)) F)/(2 m γ ω0)) *)

HilbertTransformMethod2 /@ Expand[Xsol[t]]

(* (E^(-I t ω0) (1 + E^(2 I t ω0)) F)/(2 m γ ω0) *)
```

Comment: That is a really helpful tip! You're a Mathematica wizard!

Comment: Of course, there are some interesting expressions whose Fourier transform exists, but which expand into terms whose Fourier transforms diverge.

Comment: @mikado Do you know of any specific examples I could look up?

Comment: It is easy to create artificial examples e.g. `Cosh[t]-Abs[Sinh[t]]`.  (I've not checked whether Mathematica can do this without simplifying first.  Neither of the terms have convergent Fourier transforms, though their difference does).