# Hilbert Transform in mathematica

Tags: integral-transforms, transformation

I would like to do a Hilbert transformation in Mathematica on a function. However, it does not seem to give a right result.

The [Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) transform is given by

[image]

So I did :

```
 Integrate[Sin[t]/(k - t), {t, -Infinity, Infinity}];
```

but it [does not work](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%20%20Integrate%5BSin%5Bt%5D%2F%28k%20-%20t%29%2C%20%7Bt%2C%20-Infinity%2C%20Infinity%7D%5D%3B)

The only reference I found online is this :

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Hilbert+transform+sinx

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this transform as a Mathematica code?

Thanks

Comment: See here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272806/issue-with-inverse-fourier-transform

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, this works